# How to make a triangle with CSS3?

Tags: css

How can I make this bottom div into a triangle like shown in the image? I tried the code below but the edges don't come into the center.

```
border-radius: 0 0px 100px 100px;
```

[image: Triangle]

Comment: refer to this website :) http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px;
border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangle">
    <!--Div content here -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle { 
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 60px 175px 0 175px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

See DEMO here:

**TRIANGLE DOWN**
http://jsfiddle.net/EdZ32/6/

**TRIANGLE UP**
http://jsfiddle.net/EdZ32/5/

Triangle Generator here:
http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-triangle-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

use the CSS below to achieve the triangle styling.

```
.arrow-down {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;

border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```